# SSH access to Apple Time Capsule

Tags: network-attached-storage, apple, ssh, backup

Is there any way to install or activate sshd in an Apple Time Capsule in the way you can download dd-wrt and install custom firmware on a netgear router?

I'd like to enable sshfs access to Time Capsule. And possibly install pyTivo to have it serve files to my Tivo.

Anyone done this?

Comment: Keep an eye on http://serverfault.com/questions/7098/how-to-hack-airport-extreme-to-support-usb-3g-modem

As far as I can tell there has never been an alternative OS for the Airport line and so any custom solutions are dead in the water.

Comment: A later question from the same person: http://superuser.com/q/23816/84988 "… jailbreak an Apple Time capsule? I'm interested in installing sshd for sshfs access."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present no one has successfully done this.

Two links I ran across of those trying:
http://www.hackint0sh.org/forum/f133/36987.htm
http://www.scherello.de/?id=181

Comment: https://github.com/samuelthomas2774/airport/wiki/SSH

I stumbled upon this as I was trying to figure out how to remotely reboot the Airport Extreme while having “setup over WAN” disabled, but still having VPN access to a server in the local network. Apparently using the node-acp utility it is simple as running ״acp --host airport-extreme.local --password password setprop dbug 0x3000,” then rebooting the router using “acp --host airport-extreme.local --password password reboot”

Answer (score 1):

Well... I have managed to activate `ssh` and remote login to mine ... but that alone does not mean one can install a 3rd party firmware.

```
me@myhost test % ssh root@10.0.0.3
root@10.0.0.3's password: 
Last login: Sat Nov 14 14:43:22 2020 from 10.0.0.66
Terminal type is xterm-256color.                                                                                                                        
airporttc# dmesg
...
Copyright (c) 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
    2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012
    The NetBSD Foundation, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
    The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.

NetBSD 6.0 (build.kernel-target.conf) #0: Mon Apr 29 18:35:13 PDT 2019
    root@xapp29.apple.com:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/J28/AirPortFW-79100.2/Embedded/Firmware/NetBSD/Targets/J28/release/obj/build.kernel-target.conf
total memory = 256 MB
avail memory = 229 MB
timecounter: Timecounters tick every 10.000 msec
mainbus0 (root)
cpu0 at mainbus0 core 0: 1 GHz Cortex-A9 r4p0 (Cortex core)

...
```

Maybe it is time to ask Apple to fix this security hole?

Comment: Amazing. I haven't had a time capsule in years and have moved on to using open source  firmware on my routers.